# docker image build failed

Tags: dockerfile, docker-image

i am encountering this problem on building docker image

```
[+] Building 59.0s (5/8)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                    0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                       0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/openjdk:17                                                                                                                           4.4s
 => CANCELED [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                             54.3s
 => => transferring context: 2.16GB                                                                                                                                                    54.2s
 => CACHED [1/4] FROM docker.io/library/openjdk:17@sha256:74bad65c9e59d6410bdd67d71a14e14175ddd33d654419ecfabf03ddbe70fff4                                                              0.0s
error from sender: context canceled
```

Comment: welcome - please share your Dockerfile